# Find min and max for subsets of consecutive rows - gaps and islands

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to build a query.

The input is ordered by rownumber in column 'rn' starting with 1 for each unique value in 'name' and defining a given sequence of entries in 'act'. In column 'act' it holds two values in multiple occurence, >sleep< and >wake<. The goal is to find for each consecutive set of rows of one of those values the minimum and maximum value of startt and endd.

This shall be the input:

```
name       act        rn     startt endd
---------- ---------- ------ ------ ------
jimmy      sleep      1      1      3
jimmy      wake       2      4      7
jimmy      wake       3      8      10
jimmy      sleep      4      11     13
karen      wake       1      1      4
karen      sleep      2      5      7
karen      wake       3      8      9
karen      wake       4      10     12
karen      wake       5      13     14
karen      sleep      6      15     17
karen      sleep      7      18     20
```

the desired output:

```
name       act        startt endd   
---------- ---------- ------ ------ 
jimmy      sleep      1      3      
jimmy      wake       4      10     
jimmy      sleep      11     13     
karen      wake       1      4      
karen      sleep      5      7      
karen      wake       8      14     
karen      sleep      15     20
```

The source of the input does not provide further columns. The number of members in each subset can be very much higher then in this example.

I tried different ways of aggregating, but none worked. I believe using `LEAD` and `LAGG` and further trickery might get me there, but that appears to be awfully unelegant. I have the notion it is key to differentiate each subset, i.e. create an identifier unique to all its members. With this at hand an aggregate with `min` and `max` is simple. Maybe i'm wrong. Maybe it's impossible. Maybe a self join. Maybe a recursive cte. I don't know.

So: does anybody know how to get this? Help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Thank You to Gordon Linoff, shawnt00 and the other contributors who commented. With Your advice I feel major gaps in my toolbox of logic closing.

For the interested:

```
declare @t table (
    name nvarchar(10)
    ,act nvarchar (10)
    ,startt smallint
    ,endd smallint
    )

insert into @t (
    name
    ,act
    ,startt
    ,endd
    )
values
     ('jimmy','sleep', 1,3)
    ,('jimmy','wake', 4,7)
    ,('jimmy','wake', 8,10)
    ,('jimmy','sleep', 11,13)
    ,('karen','wake', 1,4)
    ,('karen','sleep', 5,7)
    ,('karen','wake', 8,9)
    ,('karen','wake', 10,12)
    ,('karen','wake', 13,14)
    ,('karen','sleep', 15,17)
    ,('karen','sleep', 18,20)

; --- all rows, no aggregating
with 
cte as (
select 
    name
    ,act
    ,row_number() over (partition by name order by name,startt) rn
    ,row_number() over (partition by name, act order by name,startt) act_n
    ,startt
    ,endd
from
    @t )
select
    name
    ,act
    ,startt
    ,endd
    ,rn
    ,act_n
    ,rn - act_n diff
from 
    cte
order by 
    name
    ,rn

;--- aggregating for the desired ouput
with 
cte as (
select 
    name
    ,act
    ,row_number() over (partition by name order by name,startt) rn
    ,row_number() over (partition by name, act order by name,startt) act_n
    ,startt
    ,endd
from 
    @t )
select
    name
    ,act
    ,min(startt) startt
    ,max(endd)   endd
    ,min(rn)     min_rn
    ,max(rn)     max_rn
from 
    cte
group by 
    name
    ,act
    ,rn - act_n
order by 
    name
    ,min(rn)
```

Comment: This is a Gaps and Islands problem, search for that and you will find suggested solutions. Or look at the chapter 5 PDF on this page https://www.manning.com/books/sql-server-mvp-deep-dives

Comment: if the difference between endd and startt always 1 if they should be grouped together?  Or are these just sample sets and the next set is based on the changes in name,act?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to find consecutive groups of similar rows and then aggregation.  I like the difference of row numbers approach:

```
select name, act, min(startt) as startt, max(endd) as endd
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, act order by rn) as seqnum_na,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by rn) as seqnum_n
      from input i
     ) i
group by (seqnum_n - seqnum_na), name, act;
```

You can see how this works by looking at what the subquery does.

Comment: check out framed windowed functions.  You should be able to do this all i one shot.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: @MatthewWhited  maybe you could write a different answer with that solution. I still dont understand the row precceding concept even I try a few time.

Comment: It think I spoke too soon on frames.  I've used them for stats but this is slight different.  it looks more like a recursive CTE is in order.  (or a group such as this example)... but if I pull my foot out of my mouth I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you don't have any gaps in the `rn` numbering so it doesn't calculate it again.

```
with T2 as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by name, act order by rn) as grp_rn
    from T
)
select name, act, min(startt) as startt, max(endd) as endd
from T2
group by name, act, rn - grp_rn
order by name, startt;
```

http://rextester.com/CCQJJ93990

This is a typical gaps and islands query. The key here is that when you have a cluster of rows the two different numberings will increase in step and that means the difference will be a constant for the cluster. This difference increases as you work your way down the list.

Comment: Thank You for Your explanation. This trick is nice. Also good hint on the increase of the difference.