# Adding end date and time values at start row's end date and end time columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, postgis, gaps-and-islands

I am working with GPS data extracted from many `loggerid` and my table have consecutive rows with `lat` and `lon` duplicates. I want to keep only the first row of each consecutive latitude and longitude duplicates, store `datecon` and `timecon` of the last row of each consecutive latitude and longitude duplicates at the first row's `enddate` and `endtime` columns, and remove all the rows of that consecutive latitude and longitude duplicates including the last row.

This is what my table looks like:

```
id, loggerid, datecon, timecon, lat, lon
200, 1, 2018-07-18, 07:04:10, 16.694834, 100.319834
201, 1, 2018-07-18, 07:36:30, 16.694834, 100.319834
202, 1, 2018-07-18, 08:11:00, 16.694834, 100.319834
203, 1, 2018-07-18, 08:49:25, 16.851309, 100.315957
204, 1, 2018-07-18, 09:20:58, 16.851309, 100.315957
300, 2, 2018-08-20, 13:52:22, 16.947631, 100.321598
301, 2, 2018-08-20, 14:27:34, 16.947631, 100.321598
302, 2, 2018-08-20, 14:59:11, 16.392313, 100.395439
```

The output I am trying to achieve:

```
id, loggerid, datecon, timecon, enddate, endtime, lat, lon
200, 1, 2018-07-18, 07:04:10, 2018-07-18, 08:11:00, 16.694834, 100.319834
203, 1, 2018-07-18, 08:49:25, 2018-07-18, 09:20:58, 16.851309, 100.315957
300, 2, 2018-08-20, 13:52:22, 2018-08-20, 14:27:34, 16.947631, 100.321598
302, 2, 2018-08-20, 14:59:11, [null], [null], 16.392313, 100.395439
```

Does anyone know some solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem, where you want to group together consecutive rows for the same logger having the same latitude and longitude.

Here is one approach using the difference between `row_number()`s to identify the groups:

```
select
    min(id) id,
    loggerid,
    min(datecon + timecon) first_datetimecon,
    max(datecon + timecon) last_datetimecon,
    lat,
    lon
from ( 
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by loggerid order by datecon + timecon) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by loggerid, lat, lon order by datecon + timecon) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by loggerid, lat, lon
```

Note that it is not a good practice to store the date and time portions in separate columns, since it makes things more complicated when you actually need to compare datetimes values. The above query gives you the starting and ending *datetime*s of each series.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I didn't mention this in my question above, but `id` is not sequential; i.e. 401 may come before 400. Are there alternative ways of choosing the first  `id`s appear apart from `min(id)`? I tried `first_value()` but failed as the column inside the window function needs to be in group by clause as well or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: I tried the code. It doesn't group consecutive records that are latitude and longitude duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38151729/12408040) gives what I was trying to achieve. I have added a new sequential ID column as a workaround for `min(id)` or `first_value(id)` issue. For my case, it would be:

```
select  
    min(seq_id) as first_seq_id, 
    max(seq_id) as last_seq_id, 
    loggerid, 
    lat, 
    lon, 
    min(datetimecon) as first_datetimecon, 
    max(datetimecon) as last_datetimecon 
from (
    select 
         mytable.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by loggerid, lat, lon order by datetimecon) as seqnum_na,
         row_number() over (partition by loggerid order by datetimecon) as seqnum_n
    from mytable) t
group by (seqnum_n - seqnum_na), loggerid, lat, lon
```