# SQL find MIN and MAX range value for a subset of columns in SCD

Tags: sql, sql-server, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have  implemented CDC - SCD Type 2 on the customer data set.

I have implemented  CDC on large of columns but the ask is  to track behavior for only  subset of those columns.

In the below input table I have ID column for the customer and RATE_CODE as one of the CDC field and START and END DATES are the CDC changes dates.

In this I wan't to know how over a period of time  the customer data(RATE_CODE) is changing.

EX Row 1-3 has same RATE_CODE thus i need min(START_DATE) from ROW#1 and max(END_DATE) from ROW#3.

I tried applying group by on (ID,RATE_CODE) and min and max on dates but it is giving wrong value as in that case the max value will be picked from ROW#9 (for which I want a separate entry considering the ROW#6-9)

**INPUT TABLE**

| ROW NUMBER | ID | RATE_CODE | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A1 | 01-01-2021 | 18-01-2021 |
| 2 | 1 | A1 | 18-01-2021 | 25-02-2021 |
| 3 | 1 | A1 | 25-02-2021 | 15-03-2021 |
| 4 | 1 | A2 | 15-03-2021 | 28-03-2021 |
| 5 | 1 | A2 | 28-03-2021 | 28-05-2021 |
| 6 | 1 | A1 | 28-05-2021 | 28-06-2021 |
| 7 | 1 | A1 | 28-06-2021 | 12-07-2021 |
| 8 | 1 | A1 | 20-07-2021 | 28-07-2021 |
| 9 | 1 | A1 | 28-08-2021 | 13-09-2021 |
| 10 | 1 | A2 | 13-09-2021 | 13-10-2021 |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

| ID | RATE_CODE | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 01-01-2021 | 15-03-2021 |
| 1 | A2 | 15-03-2021 | 28-05-2021 |
| 1 | A1 | 28-05-2021 | 13-09-2021 |
| 1 | A2 | 13-09-2021 | 13-10-2021 |

There could be some articles or answer on the net as well but due to framing of the question I couldn't find them.

I want the solution in SQL but for the community PySpark and other languages are also welcomed.

Comment: SELECT ID,RATE_CODE,MIN(START_DATE),MAX(END_DATE) FROM #TBL GROUP BY ID,RATE_CODE

Comment: This is known as a "gaps and island" problem. Lots of examples of this; I've added a couple as dupe candidates.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the keyword. I knew it was a common scenario but didn't know how to search. In case you are aware can you help me with the keywords for other such scenario of SQL's any link or tutorials for that matter.

Comment: @PythonLearner google advanced sql queries.

Comment: Don't worry about not know what the terminology is, @PythonLearner , we all didn't know what it was at one point. Once you do know what it is though, normally due to asking how to implement the solution for such terms without knowing what it is and finding out what it is in the answer (like here), it makes searching for the answer vastly easier. :)

Comment: @Larnu . . . It is really sad that this is marked as a duplicate.  For this particular variant, there is a better solution than in either of those two answers.  But people here are so uptight about duplicate questions.

Comment: *"But people here are so uptight about duplicate questions."* *Cough* With respect, @GordonLinoff, until you *learn* where the "close as duplicate" feature is, I don't feel you can weigh in here.

Comment: Also, if you think your [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38151729/2029983) isn't good enough any more, @GordonLinoff , then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38151729/edit) it. You were [told this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408957/2029983) by a huge mass of the community. Learn from your mistakes.

Comment: @Larnu . . . Not at all.  I don't think it is a duplicate.  I think the constraints on this question are quite different.

Comment: Again, with respect @GordonLinoff , your opinion of what isn't a duplicate has been proven to be quite misaligned with the community. If this didn't answer the question, I would have expected the OP to have let us know by now with an edit and a comment (directed at myself) explaining why it is not a duplicate. The fact that they have not, and actually responded quite well to the candidates suggests that the answer has been provided by said duplicate candidates.

Comment: @Larnu . . . It is sad that someone asking a question here is not getting the best answer to their question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thought the provided solution are not exactly the same as my case but are on the same line and Since they  involve CTE (need to get idea about it as well)  so I need some time to built a logic for my case. Although I also wanted the solution in PySpark for the learning purpose and for the community but couldn't find a way to undo the Duplicate(Not reposted the question because at least I now know on which lines to works) .Incase there are better solution they are most welcomed

Comment: @PythonLearner . . . I'm not saying they don't work.  I'm saying there is a better answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In that case it would be really helpful if you can share that as well.  Different approach to the problem  will help me in understand advanced SQL part better.

Comment: @PythonLearner . . . Unfortunately, the question was closed with an inappropriate duplicate before I had an opportunity to answer.